# Interpreting signs of coefficient estimates for collinear variables in glmer

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity, lme4-nlme

I'm doing an glmer on data in which multiple participants attempt to identify multiple words. Word identification accuracy (ACC) is the dependent measure. I want to test whether two variables related to characteristics of the words (measures of lexical competition; method1 and method2) each predict unique variance in ACC. The two methods are highly correlated, but are different in theoretically interesting ways.

I can generate models that include one method each and then a model that includes both methods and use a likelihood test to evaluate whether the model with both is a better fit than the models with only one, as below (omitting random slopes here for simplicity):

```
m1 = glmer (ACC ~  method1 + (1|participants) + (1|items), data, family = binomial)
m2 = glmer (ACC ~  method2 + (1|participants) + (1|items), data, family = binomial)
m1.2 = glmer (ACC ~  method1 + method2 + (1|participants) + (1|items), data, family = binomial)

summary(m1)
Fixed effects:
             Estimate  Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    0.23743     0.08663    2.741   0.00613 ** 
method1       33.87245     5.90947    5.732  9.93e-09 ***

summary(m2) 
Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.23747    0.08658   2.743   0.0061 ** 
method2      34.12480    4.44495   7.677 1.63e-14 ***

summary(m1.2)
Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.391e-01  8.598e-02    2.78  0.00543 ** 
method1      -1.103e+03  7.288e+00 -151.39  < 2e-16 ***
method2       1.140e+03  6.692e+00  170.41  < 2e-16 ***
```

The anovas [anova(m1, m1.2), anova(m2, m1.2)]tell me that m1.2 provides a better fit than m1 or m2 alone, but I'm also interested in the direction of the effects when both are in the model (that is, are method1 and method2 pulling in the same direction?). The signs of the coefficient estimates of Method1 and Method2 are positive when entered alone, but method1 becomes negative when entered simultaneously with method 2.

However, given the degree of collinearity between method1 and method2, my understanding is that I can't trust the signs of the coefficient estimates in m1.2 (meaning they are so close to zero, the signs isn't interpretable).

How can I determine the directions of the relationships between two collinear variables and the dependent measure?

I'm aware of the residualizing technique to make the two methods orthogonal before entering them, but [Wurm & Fisicaro](http://clas.wayne.edu/Multimedia/wurm/files/Wurm%20%26%20Fisicaro%20%282014%29.pdf) have raised good objections to that method.

Comment: If you could provide some sample output that would be great. It's hard to understand what you mean by "can't trust". What are you uncertain of exactly? If you mean that you can't trust that the unique effect of method1 is not in the same direction as the effect of method1 including method2 contributions then that's a matter of interpretation, not trust. If your question is about statistical decisiveness more information would be needed such as what exactly are the method1 and method2 variables. Is it something else you don't trust?

Comment: I've added some output above. My hypothesis is that method2 would be positively correlated with accuracy and method1 would be negatively correlated when they're entered simultaneously. However, I'm concerned that the estimates are so small they may effectively be zero (and therefore the sign isn't meaningful).

Comment: Small and large comes down to the range of your predictor and response variables and what meaningful amounts of change would be. That can't be derived from just the regression output you need to relate something about the actual values. So, a coefficient of 1103 is small? Add to your question some properties of the x and y values that would allow one to assess this? What would a large change in ACC for a unit change in method1 be?